# Kafka Consumer - Read FIXED number of messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Can I create a kafka consumer to read FIXED (say 100) number of messages in Kafka ? My condition is in any case it should not exceed 100 ,less than 100 is fine.

Comment: Your requirement is strange. Say you have 1000 messages in a topic. Do you want to consume any 100 from the 1000 messages available?

Comment: Yes . I want to process all messages but in one minute I can take only 100 .I dont have any control on produce side .

Comment: Are you using Java?

Comment: Yes.Using Java for processing

Answer (score 5):

You can set `max.poll.records` to 100. It denotes the  maximum number of records returned in a single call to poll().

You can find more consumer configs here: 
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs

Comment: Will try out this and let you know.

Comment: This has some caveats .Suppose I have limit as 100 . My Kafka consumer started reading and in first iteration partition 0 assigned to this but lets suppose this partition has only 90 records .It returned 90 . In 2nd iteration lets suppose 2nd partition is assigned to it and it has 80 records Now this returned 80 records (since max limit is 100 ). So total records returned  : 80 + 90 = 170

Comment: Or another possible options is having some counter in your program.

Comment: I am doing that . But Can I set "max.poll.records" after creating a kafkaconsumer ? . i.e in above case , I will set max.poll.records = 10 in 2nd iteration

Comment: No, you can't set it after consumer creation. Kafka doesn't provide any handy feature to support like fixed size message fetching.   You can try adding some counter in your consumer application which stops it after 100 messages are consumed.

Comment: How can handle it using a counter? Once I read from the kafka, it is inside my application memory. I don't want to lose the data once my application stops.

Comment: You can commit per the offset for the messages which have been processed by the consumer. This way, if the consumer processes 50 messages out of 100 which it read initially, it can commit only 50 so, next poll will fetch the remaining 50 messages again.